# form tag is not loading inside an iframe, its getting commented out inside iframe tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, iframe

For my application, i want to have a hidden iframe with a form inside, which has some input fields. The value to the fields will be added based on the response i get from backend and then submit the form. The problem is on the browser the content inside iframe is commented out like below

[form tag in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C00Jx.png)

My html code is like below

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ddc-iframe-3ds">
    <iframe height="1" width="1" style="display: none;" >

  <form id="collectionForm" method="POST" action="https://secure-test.worldpay.com/shopper/3ds/ddc.html">
    <input type="hidden" id="ddcBin" name="Bin" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="ddcJWT" name="JWT" value="" />
  </form>
</iframe>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

in the below link, to integrate with payments, it is suggested to use hidden iframe with a form inside
[3DS payment integration](https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/directintegration/3ds2#device-data-collection-ddc-)

Comment: That's not what an iframe is, you can't use it to hide content from your main page. An iframe needs an url that it displays. Use a div instead.

Comment: @cloned thank you for the response, i am doing a payment integration and it requires to have a hidden iframe that has a form. later we submit the form.